Why are simple numerical proportions usually expressed in percent?
In English, proportions that add up to ten are almost always expressed as percentages, such as “60-40”. We do this even when we don’t know the proportions to a precision of hundredths, and it would be simpler both verbally and conceptually to say “6-4” (as is done in some other languages).
How long has this been prevalent, and why?

I don't have an answer wrt the specific questions, "How long has this been prevalent, and why?" But can suggest a canonical source for addressing it, books and papers by the prolific Gerd Gigerenzer https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=gigerenzer

It's common in day-to-day usage to use other things e.g. cooking and cocktail recipes often use "parts" in low numbers. Betting odds in the UK are expressed as e.g. 3 to 2, or 8 to 1, or 13 to 8, or 100 to 1 (totalling 5, 9, 21 or 101). It's common to talk about "one in four people" etc. Certainly the English speaking world uses per mille less than some European countries but I think you're just noticing all the cases when 100 is used and ignoring the rest.

Note that the dairy product is half-and-half, not 50-50 :)

The usage seems to be of fairly recent origin. 'Fifty-fifty' is arguably the prototypical example:


OED's earliest evidence for 'fifty-fifty' is from 1913, in the writing of P. G. Wodehouse, writer.


[OED]
Google ngrams correspondingly show a vast increase in usage during the 1910s, but there are a few prior examples (and for 'sixty-forty') which I sadly can't examine further.
I've only a couple of guesses as to why 'sixty-forty' rather than 'three to two'

It sounds a little more sophisticated. But we're happy with 'in the ratio of three to two'.
The intended fractional breakdown is more obvious with 'sixty-forty' than with 'three-two' (which sounds like a soccer score) or say 'five to two' which sounds like a time. @Fe₂O₃ (if I've spelled that right) has a similar thought.

